# Nest.js with yarn workspaces (not nest.js monorepo)

Tags: node.js, nestjs, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to create a yarn workspace monorepo where some of the modules will be nest.js modules. The issue I'm facing is that nest.js monorepo has a particular way of setup that is not compatible with yarn workspaces, see the following example:

```
packages/
├─ entrypoint/
│  ├─ main.ts <~ here I'll create a nest instance using all other modules
│  ├─ lambda.ts <~ lambda express app for main
│  ├─ local.ts <~ local express app for main
├─ nestjs-module-1/
│  ├─ index.ts <~ here I want to export my module
├─ nestjs-module-2/
│  ├─ index.ts <~ here I want to export my module
├─ not-a-nestjs-module/
│  ├─ index.ts <~ just something else, not nest.js
├─ package.json <~ nest.js monorepo forces me to have this but this module does not exists on yarn workspaces as it's configured to /packges/*
```

Comment: Adding this comment, because I'm interested in this too..

Comment: also interested on this. Did you managed to do it?

Comment: also interested